# Kivy--how to bind a function to a checkbox when activated

Tags: python, checkbox, kivy

I have a Python program in which I use kivy's checkboxes.

Is there a way to let the program call a function the instant when the checkbox is disabled/enabled?

Please note, the active property wont work since this is only once, one would have to use a infinite while loop to check whether the user activated it which would make everything complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
```

## ...

```
def do_something(checkbox, value):
    # Do something

checkbox = CheckBox()
checkbox.bind(active=do_something)
```

Comment: Ok, il try, did not know that you8 can do it this simple, cuz in the documentation it says that active is a booleanproperty

Comment: @Cid-El it would be nice to accpet the answer. thank you

Comment: thanks, I think it would be nice too, but as far as i know stack overflow is for accepting answers THAT ANSWERS THE QUESTION and up until now i have not tried it out,

Comment: another thing, if it were you that gave my question a down vote, on what grounds did you do it? my question was fully acceptable, and as far as i know it is not a duplicate, so if you have something wrong with the question, instead of just down voting, and asking me to accept the answer, would you mind to tell me what was wrong with the question?

Comment: Oh, I have to apolegise, I was in the wrong, I was mad, sorry, your answer suits my purposses completely

Comment: @Cid-El No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use on_release keyword with lambda function in it. Like:

```
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox

def do_something(checkbox, active, value): ## value is optional
    if active:
       print(value)
 

checkbox = CheckBox()
checkbox.bind(on_release = lambda x: do_something(x, x.active, "hello"))
```